# Running a script from a particular Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to put together a code and want the code to choose a selected sheet rather than the active sheet - the Sheet that I want the code to run from has been renamed 'Training Record':

```
var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues()
```

The rest of the code is as follows and runs as intended without the change that I need:

```
function createTrainingDocs() {
  var tempID ='1dyQIK3OCPWXDLydg-MKRhL43CACtyQQDG3VUR11PlH8'
  var folderID = '1UpVdcyuP-c_PZVx8uEBRVEH7m_zBnzvb'

var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues()
//console.log(data)
data.forEach((row,i)=>{

console.log(row[2]+', '+row[1]+' Training Log')
var newDocID = DriveApp.getFileById(tempID).makeCopy(row[2]+', '+row[1]+' Training Log',DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID)).getId()
var body = DocumentApp.openById(newDocID).getBody()
body.replaceText('{{Name}}',row[1]+' '+row[2])
body.replaceText('{{School Name}}',row[0])
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i+1,4).setValue(newDocID)
})

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues()
```

To

```
var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var data = spread.getSheetByName("Training Record").getDataRange().getValues()
```